# Search file for input Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am writing a program to read a text file of zip codes that should print the location of the zip code when the correct number is input. However, I am having trouble writing the error message. I have tried various methods and cannot get the error message to print, here is what I have:

```
try:
    myFile=open("zipcodes.txt") #Tries to open file user entered
except: 
    print "File can't be opened:", myFile #If input is invalid filename, print error
    exit()

zipcode = dict() #List to store individual sentences
line = myFile.readline() #Read each line of entered file

ask = raw_input("Enter a zip code: ")

if ask not in line:
    print "Not Found."
else:
    for line in myFile:
       words = line.split()
       if words[2] == ask:
          zipcode = words[0:2]
for value in zipcode:
    print value,
```

Some sample ZIP codes:

```
Abbeville         AL 36310
Abernant          AL 35440
Acmar             AL 35004
Adamsville        AL 35005
Addison           AL 35540
Adger             AL 35006
Akron             AL 35441
Alabaster         AL 35007
```

Comment: Can you add part of "zipcodes.txt" to question?. First 3 lines will be enough.

Comment: There are some samples posted below the code.

Comment: Method `readline` reads only 1 line. I thing you need `read`.

Comment: didn't make a difference

Comment: You mean is doesn't print anything at all?

Comment: Yes, nothing is printed.

Comment: Than it's found. You just miss it.

Comment: That doesn't help if nothing gets printed.

Comment: It also prints nothing when you input an incorrect value.

Comment: It strange that it doesn't print any thing when input is incorrect. Can you add something into `zipcode` dict, right after creation. And check will it be printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the beginning:

```
try:
    myFile=open("zipcodes.txt") 
except: 
    print "File can't be opened:", myFile # if open fail then myFile will be undefined.
    exit()

zipcode = dict() # you creating dict, but you never add something into it.

line = myFile.readline() # this will read only first line of file, not each

ask = raw_input("Enter a zip code: ") 

if ask not in line:  
    # it will print not found for any zipcode except zipcode in first line
    print "Not Found."
else:
    # because you already read 1 line of myFile
    # "for line in " will go from second line to end of file

    for line in myFile: # 1 line already readed. Continue reading from second 
       words = line.split() 
       if words[2] == ask: # If you don't have duplicate of first line this will never be True
          zipcode = words[0:2]

# So here zipcode is an empty dict. Because even if "ask is in line"
# You never find it because you don't check line 
# where the ask is (the first line of file).
for value in zipcode:
    # print never executed becouse zipcode is empty
    print value,
```

Comment: This explain why it don't print anything when input is correct. I'm not sure why it don't print "Not found" for any input except "36310". I run this code, with zipcode.txt that you add into question, and it always print "Not found" for other zipcodes.

Comment: Figured out on my own, closed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the significance of enterFile. You should see the error message if you remove enterFile from the exception because it doesn't appear to be defined.

Comment: That was something i forgot to take out from old code, I will fix it

Comment: The problem is when I change if ask not in line: to if ask in line: the code works, but I get no error message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you need two phases in this program:

1. Read zipcodes.txt and build your directory.
2. Ask the user for a ZIP code; print the corresponding location.

**Your current "positive" logic** is

```
else:
    for line in myFile:
       words = line.split()       # Get the next line from zipcodes.txt
       if words[2] == ask:        # If this ZIP code matches the input,
          zipcode = words[0:2]    # assign the line's three fields as a list.

# Variable zipcode now contains a single line's data, all three fields.
#   You threw away the empty dictionary.

for value in zipcode:    # Print all three fields of the one matching line.
    print value,
```

**Needed Logic** (in my opinion)

```
# Part 1: read in the ZIP code file
# For each line of the file:
#    Split the line into location and ZIP_code
#    zipcode[ZIP_code] = location

# Part 2: match a location to the user's given ZIP code
# Input the user's ZIP code, "ask"
# print zipcode[ask]
```

Does this pseduo-code get you moving toward a solution?

Comment: Not really. The main issue was that the if ask not in: statement was not working correctly, and I do not know why.